# In IE 11, the ClickOnce *.application link fails to open

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11, clickonce

The machine is using Windows 7 and IE 11 to open the link. Instead of opening the application, a new blank window is opened. The file URL is similar to the following: http://website.intranet/windows.application

When I enter the URL in manually and open it, the program launches without a problem.

It's strange because the link opens fine on other installations of Windows 7 with IE 11.

Comment: Try and reset the IE11 configuration